# Fixed Background for iPhone app using Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Can't seem to find a way to fix a graphic - a light graphic that would remain static as the user navigates from scene to scene. Have been combing forums for a few days, but most answers point to MainWindow.xib, which isn't generated for a storyboard project.  Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to manually add UIImageView to your window and then set 0 background transparency
for all other views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but not sure what you mean by 'window' here.  Say I've got a navigation controller with four views chained - are you saying that I should put the background graphic in the first view and set the other three to transparent?  (I've tried this with no joy.)  Sorry if I'm missing something blindingly obvious... complete noob.

Comment: I mean [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow. You just add view with required image on your program startup and then set backgroundColor for all you views as [UIColor clearColor]

Comment: You rule - this put me on the right path.  I've spelled out what I did in an answer hoping it might save others an hour or five... thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Here’s what I was able to cobble together thanks to advice from @Max.  Like I said, very new to this, so if this code needs tuning please leave a comment so I don’t lead others astray.

Add the image to the app’s main window in the AppDelegate’s didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method :

```
UIImageView *myGraphic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myGraphic.png"]];
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview: myGraphic];
[self.window.rootViewController.view sendSubviewToBack: myGraphic];
```

Then, to make your views transparent so the background shows through - in your  viewController class/es, add to viewDidLoad method:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

(And note if you try to decrease the transparency through the alpha property for the view via the Attributes Inspector, it will make everything transparent on that view -buttons, etc - that’s why it needs to be done programmatically.)

Sure, it’s not thoroughly tested. But for now it’s working and it’s a thing of beauty.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it -- it may not be the best -- can be that you subclass a UIView, and set the UIView instance in all of your viewControllers in the storyboard an instance of your cutomized UIView class, which contains your graphic as a background.

Comment: Wow you guys are fast... thanks for the suggestion. I think this would have a similar effect to what I've done - just adding the graphic to each scene... problem is that it's a cropped graphic that sits in the corner, so when the scene animates from one to the next, the graphic zings across the top in all it's funky, cropped glory looking... not so great.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to tackle this programmatically, within each view controller, set:

```
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
```

in `viewDidLoad`

I'm sure some tweaking would allow you to apply this principle throughout the program from the app delegate, or by using a singleton.

Using this solution, though, you're still going to have to make some method call within each view controller where you want this style applied.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - did try but it creates the same effect as dragging an image view onto each scene, with the image moving as the scene animates.