# How to set the background image of the main view in XCode storyboard editor?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to set a background image for my main superview in the story board editor without creating another view(just for a background image). I can change the class of my main view to UIImageView, but the editor will not show me the option to specify a background image. How can I make this work?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Sorry..

Comment: you can't, you can only set an ImageView over your view and set frame equals to view and show some image.

Comment: Look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265635/fixed-background-for-iphone-app-using-storyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but you won't get visual feedback from the storyboard. Under the Identity inspector (cmd+option+3), there is a pane for setting user-defined runtime attributes, and setting the `backgroundColor` to a `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` should work just fine. I would however, for clarity, keep that sort of stuff in the `viewDidLoad`-method

Comment: can you explain where i can get identity inspector. I am stuck with same problem.

Comment: When you have selected a view in a storyboard, or xib, press command+option+3 on your keyboard, and it should appear